# Wet vent question

Tags: vent, wet

[image]

I'm building a little apartment above my new garage and am hoping to wet vent everything like in the above crude picture.

In case it's not clear: a kitchen sink and lav are at the top of the line, then a shower and, at the end, a toilet. All branches are super short and the wet vent run from toilet to the lav/kitchen sink is 8 ft.

The numbers are the pipe size.

Questions...
Does this look ok?

And, at the risk of asking a stupid question, if I oversize the long run from the toilet up to the vent stack at the lav/ kitchen sink do I need a soli stack at the end? I'd like to have just one vent stack at the lav end and wet vent everything else thru that.

Really appreciate any advice here!
Martin